# ASP.NET MVC - Get TModel property value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC app written in C#. My app has a very specific, one-off extension method. Currently, my extension method looks like this

```
public static MvcHtmlString CreateControl<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items, object htmlAttributes = null)
{
  var name = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
  var metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
  var model = htmlHelper.ViewData.Model;
  ...

  int i = 0;
  i = i + 1;
}
```

I set a breakpoint on the line that says `int i = 0;` In the "watch" window within Visual Studio, I can see the list of values in `model`. `model` has a property named "MyValue". While I can see it in the "watch" window, I cannot figure out how to get the value of "MyValue" from my code. `model` is a `TModel`. I can't seem to do a type conversion on it. In addition, I do not see a helper function or anything.

How do I get a property value from a `TModel` object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> model is a `TModel`

`TModel` is not a *type* - it is a *generic parameter*.  Your extension method is generic, meaning it could be run with *any* type of model.  There's no way for the compiler to know at compile time what properties the model has, so there's no way to access them at compile time without reflection, casting, or dynamic, all of which are not run-time safe.

> My app has a very specific, one-off extension method

No, that method is *generic*.  It can work with *any* type of model.  If you want it to be specific to one model type then don't genericize the model type:

```
                                                                  V----- specific type ----------------V
public static MvcHtmlString CreateControl<TValue>(this HtmlHelper<MyModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<MyModel, TValue>> expression, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items, object htmlAttributes = null)
{
  var name = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
  var metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
  var model = htmlHelper.ViewData.Model;
  ...

  int i = 0;
  i = i + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have a type `TModel` that requires it to have the same property each time. I would make all of these types implement an interface and add a constraint like this:

```
public interface IMyModel
{
    MyValue { get; set; }
}
```

Now add the constraint:

```
public static MvcHtmlString CreateControl<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items, object htmlAttributes = null) 
    where TModel : IMyModel
{
    var myModel = (IMyModel)htmlHelper.ViewData.Model;
    //Now you can read the property:
    var value = myModel.MyValue;
}
```